# how to convert material ui pure reactjs functions to es6 classes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react Material UI in an application, but found some missing logic with my react code. Below code is working as expected

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { fade,makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';


/* AppBar*/
//import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
/*App bar */

import  ImgMediaCard from './ImgMediaCard';

import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';

import DemoCarousel from './MCarousel'

var gridListStyle = {  
  marginLeft: "40px"
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'block',
    },
  },
  search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: 200,
    },
  },
  sectionDesktop: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
  },
  sectionMobile: {
    display: 'flex',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  }  
}));
/*end App bar work*/
const useGridStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    // padding: theme.spacing(2),
    // textAlign: 'center',
    // color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

function App() {

  const Gridclasses = useGridStyles();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  };

  const handleMobileMenuOpen = event => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const onRegisterClick = () => {
    debugger;
    //if(userFound){
        return  <Redirect  to="/RegisterBuyer/" />
   // }
 }

  let nums = Array.from(Array(40).keys());
  const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
  const renderMobileMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>   
      <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" />    
     </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>     
        <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
            <MailIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Messages</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton aria-label="show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={11} color="secondary">
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Notifications</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <div className={Gridclasses.root}>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={Gridclasses.paper}>

      <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
            Shopping Center
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>          
          <IconButton  aria-label="" color="inherit" onClick={onRegisterClick}> Sign Up             
            </IconButton> 
            <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                <MailIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="show 17 new notifications" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="secondary">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
       </div>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>     
      <GridList cols={3} style={gridListStyle} cellHeight={"auto"}>
      {nums.map(n => {
        return (
          <GridListTile key={n}>
            <ImgMediaCard key={n} num={n} />
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
    </GridList>    

    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
        <Paper className={Gridclasses.paper}>  <DemoCarousel />
        </Paper>
      </Grid>      

    </Grid>      
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But When i try to convert the above code into ES6 class then

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { fade,makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';


/* AppBar*/
//import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
/*App bar */

import  ImgMediaCard from './ImgMediaCard';

import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';

import DemoCarousel from './MCarousel'

var gridListStyle = {  
  marginLeft: "40px"
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'block',
    },
  },
  search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: 200,
    },
  },
  sectionDesktop: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
  },
  sectionMobile: {
    display: 'flex',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  }  
}));
/*end App bar work*/
const useGridStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    // padding: theme.spacing(2),
    // textAlign: 'center',
    // color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

const Gridclasses = useGridStyles();
const classes = useStyles();  

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props)
    this.state = {
      anchorEl: null,
      mobileMoreAnchorEl: null   
    }      

     const isMenuOpen = Boolean(this.state.anchorEl);
     const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(this.state.mobileMoreAnchorEl);  
}


  /*
   const Gridclasses = useGridStyles();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null); 
  */


  render()
  {


    const handleProfileMenuOpen = event => {

      this.setState({ open: true, anchorEl: event.currentTarget });

    };

    const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {

      this.setState({ open: false, mobileMoreAnchorEl: null });
    };


    const handleMenuClose = () => {

      this.setState({ open: false, anchorEl: null });
      handleMobileMenuClose();
    };

    const handleMobileMenuOpen = event => {
           this.setState({ open: true, mobileMoreAnchorEl: event.currentTarget });
    };

    const onRegisterClick = () => {
      //debugger;
      //if(userFound){
          return  <Redirect  to="/RegisterBuyer/" />
     // }
    }

    let nums = Array.from(Array(40).keys());
    const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
    const renderMenu = (
      <Menu
        anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        id={menuId}
        keepMounted
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        open={isMenuOpen}
        onClose={handleMenuClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    );

    const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
    const renderMobileMenu = (
      <Menu
        anchorEl={this.state.mobileMoreAnchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        id={mobileMenuId}
        keepMounted
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        open={isMobileMenuOpen}
        onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
      >
        <MenuItem>   
        <Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" />    
       </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>     
          <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
            <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
              <MailIcon />
            </Badge>
          </IconButton>
          <p>Messages</p>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <IconButton aria-label="show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
            <Badge badgeContent={11} color="secondary">
              <NotificationsIcon />
            </Badge>
          </IconButton>
          <p>Notifications</p>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="account of current user"
            aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            color="inherit"
          >
            <AccountCircle />
          </IconButton>
          <p>Profile</p>
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    );


  return (
    <div className={Gridclasses.root}>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper className={Gridclasses.paper}>

      <div className={classes.grow}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
            Shopping Center
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.grow} />
          <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>          
          <IconButton  aria-label="" color="inherit" onClick={onRegisterClick}> Sign Up             
            </IconButton> 
            <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                <MailIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="show 17 new notifications" color="inherit">
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="secondary">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
       </div>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>     
      <GridList cols={3} style={gridListStyle} cellHeight={"auto"}>
      {nums.map(n => {
        return (
          <GridListTile key={n}>
            <ImgMediaCard key={n} num={n} />
          </GridListTile>
        );
      })}
    </GridList>    

    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
        <Paper className={Gridclasses.paper}>  <DemoCarousel />
        </Paper>
      </Grid>    
    </Grid>      
  </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;







**const isMenuOpen = Boolean(this.state.anchorEl);
const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(this.state.mobileMoreAnchorEl);**
<Menu
        anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        id={menuId}
        keepMounted
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        **open={isMenuOpen}**
        onClose={handleMenuClose}
      >

 <Menu
        anchorEl={this.state.mobileMoreAnchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        id={mobileMenuId}
        keepMounted
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        **open={isMobileMenuOpen}**
        onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
      >
```

line shows following error messages:

```
'isMobileMenuOpen' is assigned a value but never used.
'isMenuOpen' is assigned a value but never used.
'isMenuOpen' is not defined.
'isMobileMenuOpen' is not defined.
```

I'm a newbie with react. What should I do in my code?

I've grabbed the example code for a menus and cards from here: https://material-ui.com

Application built with

```
{
  "react": "16.12.0", 
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0", 
  "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
  "redux": "^4.0.4"
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.2"
}
```

The container uses the react component, which is just repeating an a Card.

Output: Menus, App Bar and Cards should work perfectly.

I tried to follow guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve the issue.

Thank you **Jacob**, I already had tried this. Code compile successfully  but then there are some other errors.
See the errors now.
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
4 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to a class?

Comment: Hi Ryan, please see in my second section of code block and scroll down.

Comment: The code won't tell me **why** you're doing this.

Comment: I am converting first section (of code) to ES6 classes, handlers, const and functions (Second section of code). Because this is a new way to write proper code. My first code is working fine. I just want to convert it in second.

Comment: @maifs you shouldn't make any efforts to convert functional components to class components. Functional components are more performance wise comparing to class components and functional components are much easier to work with.

Comment: @maifs functional components are a very proper way to write your components, you really don't need to convert them to class components.

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you Christos.

Comment: ES6 classes are **NOT** the new way to write proper React code. Function components are [the preferred approach for new React code](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone is saying, you shouldn't need to convert to a class. To answer your question on the errors, though, they aren't really related to React, just plain JavaScript. Notice that you're defining constants in your class *constructor* function:

```
constructor() {
  // ...
  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(this.state.anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(this.state.mobileMoreAnchorEl);  
}
```

...but those aren't being used in the constructor function (hence the linting warnings you're getting). They're referenced in the `render()` function, but since they're not declared in that scope, those variables will be undefined. Variables declared in one function won't be seen in peer functions, not even if declared in constructors.

You'll want to move your variable declarations to the render function.

Comment: jacob, check my reply in my post

Comment: The new error tells you all you need to know; if you're using hooks (`useState`, `useEffect`, etc), you cannot use class-based components. They're solely there for function components.

Comment: jacob, than how can i use these kind of hooks in a class ? can you suggest me in your above post? your reply 'll be really appreciated.

Comment: It's impossible. Hooks are specifically for non-class-based components.

Comment: Jacob, than what is the alternative approach to achieve the similar task for a class ?